# Drop outliers from a column that contains a string and then integers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am having issues dropping outliers from a certain column in a dataframe. I have a massive dataframe but the most important column looks like this:

| Weight |
| --- |
| In kilograms |
| 10000000 |
| 70 |
| 92 |
| ... |

I am trying to drop rows depending on outliers in this column, i.e. if the weight is an outlier then the whole row is dropped. The issue is whenever I use this code:

```
col=(dataframe['Weight'].drop(index=0))
col=col.apply(pd.to_numeric)
Q1=col.quantile(0.25)
Q2=col.quantile(0.75)
IQR=Quart3-Quart1
dataframe=dataframe[col>(Q1-(1.5*IQR))]
dataframe=dataframe[col<(Q3+(1.5*IQR))]
```

I get the following error caused by the 2nd line:

```
ValueError: Unable to parse string "In kilograms" at position 0
```

When I remove the second line I still get an error because even though I have dropped the first row for some reason it still is using the first row:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: Are you sure you load the data correctly? Please include the loading script if possible. I think it shouldn't contain the "In kilograms" here. If you think the data is loaded correctly and only the row should be removed, you could filter the column to include only int number.

Comment: @Minh-TuanNguyen I'm not 100% sure what you mean by loading script but this is the code I used to load the file  `dataframe=pd.read_csv('weights_and_info.csv')` . How would I filter it to only include numbers?

Comment: What I mean is I think you can remove the first few rows if those rows contain unnecessary information. You can experiment with skiprows param in the read_csv function.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html